Is slug important for the Homepage?
I realize that by default the WordPress site router is designed so that the homepage slug doesn't matter.

But how will the site behave if the main page has a completely different slug? Here's an example: the site client created a duplicate of the Home page and set the original page's status to Draft. As a result, the main page now has the slug home-2 instead of home. Could this affect indexing or any other site indicators? *I can't change slug name for Homepage.

whenever you change URL it might affect the indexing of the page. If slug is changed but there is no impact on the URL itself, there should not be an impact related to SEO

This is actually the question. I don't understand how the assigned Home page is routed in WordPress. I understand that for other pages it is critical and need to configure 301 redirect, but how to be with the Home page?

home page usually have the site's root url. I can't realy imagine it being any different although I am sure you can hack it differently. As this is an hard coded URL, the slug is not important. to say it differently, it is not that you set the page to be the home page, you set the content of the page to be displayed at the root URL.
